# Inserting every <body> element inside a page-wrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, footer

The problem is with a sliding-up footer, which is triggered by clicking on an up-arrow. The footer is positioned inside of the page-wrap(as everything is), and instead of sliding up/appearing inside of the page-wrap container as it should, it slides-up on top of it. The page-wrap container acts as a frame with rounded corners for the whole content of the page/website and all body elements are supposed to be inserted inside of it.

I tried several approaches to resolve the issue, including rearranging the HTML elements, adjusting the z-index values in the CSS, and tweaking the JavaScript code, but none of these efforts produced the desired result. I was expecting the footer to slide up inside the page-wrap container and not be positioned on top of everything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Helvetica+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Retro Step</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-wrap">
        <footer class="slide-up-footer">
            <div class="footer-text">
            <p>FREE SHIPPING IN PORTUGAL / IN EUROPE FROM 150€ / EASY RETURNS</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-text2">
            <a href="#about">ABOUT</a><a href="#about">TERMS</a><a href="#about">PRIVACY</a><a href="#about">COOKIE SETTINGS</a><a href="#about">SUPPORT</a>
            </div>
            <div class="sign-up-promos">
            <div id="info-text"></div>
            <form id="newsletter-form" action="your-newsletter-signup-action" method="post" novalidate>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Sign up for exclusive promos, popular releases & more" id="email-input" onfocus="displayInfo(), displaySecondInfo()" type="submit">
            </form>
            <div id="info-text2"></div>       
            </div>
            
            <div class="footer-creds">
                © GRUPO 15, 2023. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED. TW / TSIW
            </div>
        </footer>
        <div class="up-arrow" id="up-arrow">
            <span class="custom-class">^</span>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
html {
    scroll-behavior:smooth;
  }

  body {
    font-family: 'Adobe Caslon Pro Bold', sans-serif;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  body h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .page-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .page-wrap h1 {
    margin: 0;
  }
  p {
    line-height: 3;
  }
  
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: none;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  .slide-up-footer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    font: 9px SuisseIntl-Regular, sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -1000px; /* or another value that will hide the footer */
    width: 100vw;
    height: 15%;
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    background-color: white;
    
  }
  
  .slide-up-footer.show {
    top: 500px;
  }
  
  .footer-text {
    display: grid;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    font: 9px SuisseIntl-Regular, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
  }
  
  .footer-text2 {
    font: 9px SuisseIntl-Regular, sans-serif;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    color: black;
    text-align: top;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .footer-text2 a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin: 0px 10px;
  }
  
  .footer-text2 a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: black;
  }
  
  .footer-creds {
    font: 9px SuisseIntl-Regular, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-row: 3/4;
    color: black;
    text-align: top;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    align-items: end;

  }
  
  .up-arrow {
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: 2rem;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .custom-class{
    font-weight: bold;
    font: 20px SuisseIntl-Regular, sans-serif;
    color:black;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  

  .sign-up-promos {
    display: grid;
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr ;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
    float: right;
    right: 20px;
  }
  
  .sign-up-promos form {
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  }
  
  
  .sign-up-promos label {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  
  .sign-up-promos input {
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    font: 10px SuisseIntl-Regular, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 270px;
  }
  
  .sign-up-promos input::placeholder {
    font: 10px SuisseIntl-Regular, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    
  }
  #email-input:focus {
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
  }
  
  .sign-up-promos input:focus {
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
  }
  input:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
  #info-text {
    display: grid;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    align-items: flex-end;
    transition: visibility 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  #info-text2 {
    width: 270px; /* or any other value you prefer */
    display: grid;
    grid-row: 3/4;
    align-items: center;
    transition: visibility 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  #info-text.visible {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    transition: visibility 0.5s, transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  #info-text2.visible {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(10px);
    transition: visibility 0.5s, transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
```

```
// Get the up arrow element
const upArrow = document.getElementById("up-arrow");
const footer = document.querySelector(".slide-up-footer");
let isOpen = false;

// Add an event listener to toggle the "show" class
upArrow.addEventListener("click", toggleFooter);

function toggleFooter() {
  if (isOpen) {
    footer.style.bottom = "-100%";
    upArrow.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
    upArrow.style.bottom = "0";
  } else {
    footer.style.bottom = "0";
    upArrow.style.bottom = "12%";
    upArrow.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
  }
  isOpen = !isOpen;
}

function displayInfo() {
  document.getElementById("info-text").innerHTML = "Enter email:";
  document.getElementById("info-text").classList.add("visible")
}

function displaySecondInfo() {
  document.getElementById("info-text2").innerHTML = "By signing up, you confirm you are over 16 years of age and you want to receive GOAT emails. Please see our Terms & Conditions and Privacy Policy for more details.";
  document.getElementById("info-text2").classList.add("visible")
}

function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^\S+@\S+.\S+$/;
  return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
  }

document.getElementById("newsletter-form").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  var emailInput = document.getElementById("email-input");
  if (!validateEmail(emailInput.value)) {
  // display an error message
  document.getElementById("info-text2").innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address.";
  setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("email-input").value = "";
  document.getElementById("info-text2").innerHTML = "By signing up, you confirm you are over 16 years of age and you want to receive GOAT emails. Please see our Terms & Conditions and Privacy Policy for more details.";
  }, 1000);
  } else {
    // update the text of info-text
    document.getElementById("info-text").innerHTML = "Thank you for subscribing!";
    document.getElementById("info-text2").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("info-text").classList.add("submited");
  
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("info-text").innerHTML = "Enter email:";
      document.getElementById("info-text2").innerHTML = "By signing up, you confirm you are over 16 years of age and you want to receive GOAT emails. Please see our Terms & Conditions and Privacy Policy for more details.";
      document.getElementById("info-text").classList.remove("submited");
      emailInput.value = '';
    }, 1500);
  }
  });
  
  let slideUpFooter = document.querySelector(".slide-up-footer");
  let infoText = document.getElementById("info-text");
  let infoText2 = document.getElementById("info-text2");
  
  let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
        // footer is not in view, reset form
        document.getElementById("email-input").value = "";
        document.getElementById("info-text").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("info-text2").innerHTML = "";
        infoText.removeAttribute("class");
        infoText2.removeAttribute("class");
      }
    });
  });
  
  observer.observe(slideUpFooter);
  
  
document.getElementById("email-input").addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  // check if the email input is empty
  if (event.target.value.trim() === "") {
    // display the original messages
    document.getElementById("info-text").innerHTML = "Enter email:";
    document.getElementById("info-text2").innerHTML = "By signing up, you confirm you are over 16 years of age and you want to receive GOAT emails. Please see our Terms & Conditions and Privacy Policy for more details.";
    document.getElementById("info-text").classList.remove("submited");
  }
});
```

Comment: You may need to use JS to set a padding-bottom on the page equal to the footer's height when the up arrow is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I added a fixed position to the page-wrap element and set its top, right, left, and bottom properties to 10 pixels each. This positions the element in the center of the page. I also set a white background and a border radius of 30 pixels to create the rounded border.

Finally, I added a button to the page and some other components.
This allows you to test the appearance of the rounded border with additional elements on the page.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

I was able to create a page with a rounded inside body border by using the following code:

```css
body {
  background: #5bb0ff;
}

.page-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.page-wrap h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  line-height: 3;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.texture-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-image: url("images/texture.png");
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: translateZ(1px);
  z-index:2
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Helvetica+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="teststyle.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Retro Step</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-wrap">

        <h1>Rounded inside body border</h1>
      
        <button>Add text</button>
       
    </div>
    <div class="texture-overlay"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Much better, but lead with your explanation. Don't throw a bunch of code up and explain it later. We don't even know that's down there at first. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const footer = document.querySelector(".slide-up-footer");
```

> .slide-up-footer {
> display: grid;
> position: fixed;
> bottom: -1000px; /* or another value that will hide the footer */
> width: 100vw;
> ...

The problem your script is applying the slide-up effect directly to the footer. In that moment footer is "detached" from the container .page-wrap

You should modify your script to apply the slide-up effect (adding a new class) directly to the .page-wrap-footer
or you need to apply the style and rounded borders directly to footer, removing it from the .page-wrap parent.